# Why is there loss of power between solar inverter and utility meter?

Tags: solar-energy, power-grid

I have an on-grid 10 kW system installed with two-way recording meter. Recently I have noticed that units generated as shown by inverter are more than the units recorded by utility meter. Previously, there was no remarkable difference in units produced and recorded by both inverter and utility meter.

So on a good day, if my inverter says that it has generated 50 units, units recorded on utility meter are 41, 9 kW loss on a day, which is huge.

Utility company says meter is good, no fault at their end, and to contact solar company. Solar company says everything is good, inverter is generating units, and to contact utility. Here I am stuck in middle where difference has increased to almost 2000 kW so far.

Any suggestions on anything I can ask my electrician to test? Because I feel that units lost during the day are not lost but rather being recorded as my consumption (my own theory as my consumption has surged without any apparent reason).

Any clues will help me getting this mystery resolved.

Comment: Did you use 9kWh inside your house?

Comment: No, this system has always been working in isolation and i never consume electricity generated by this system. Let's say the way it is connected to grid doesn't allow that

Comment: Re, "I never consume electricity generated by this system..." Are you saying that you have two separate utility meters? One for power that is used within your home and a separate one for the power that is fed to the utility by the solar system?

Comment: Technically yes, but there is single meter which shows both power consumed and power added to grid separately. There is no netting

Comment: @FawadPasha Do you mean to say that the difference is about 48 million watt-hours, so far? You write "2000 kW", which I might interpret as meaning "2000 kW-days". But is that really a 41.9 kW-hr difference and you generate 50 kW-hr, leaving only 9.1 kW-hr that they account for? So you are missing about 2000 kW-hr, so far?

Comment: @FawadPasha when you use your own power, does it count as power produced AND power consumed? both at the same time?

Comment: It's physically impossible for a single power meter to measure anything _but_ the net power that is used or produced by everything that's behind it. If the meter has two separate accumulators, then it almost certainly uses only one at a time: It would switch from using one when the net power is positive to using the other when the net power is negative. That would enable the company to bill you for power used at a different rate from the rate at which they buy back power.

Comment: (@periblepsis: I read a difference of 9 kWh between utility's reading of 41 kWh and inverter's 50 kWh in one day, accumulated to 2000 kWh over some (250 day-ish) period observed.)

Comment: @greybeard This, ***41, 9 kW loss on a day, which is huge*** is what made my mind head in the direction it went. (I took the comma to be an EU-style decimal point.) But you read this another way. Interesting. My mistake I believe, now that I look more closely at it! Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 6):

> Technically yes, but there is single meter which shows both power
> consumed and power added to grid separately. There is no netting

I don't think the system is working the way you think it is.  You can't be exporting power to the grid and importing power from the grid through the same meter at the same time.  That's not physically possible.

If it's a sunny day, and you are using electricity in your home, then some of that solar electricity is powering your home.  Only the electricity that you don't use gets exported to the grid and measured by the utility company's meter.

Answer (score 2):

Exported energ = solar energy - domestic load energy.

It would be directly analogous to pumping 20 L/hour from your private well and feeding into the water grid. If you consume 12 L/h then there is 8 L/h left to export to the grid.

Your meter has two readouts: one for energy in; the other for energy out. The reason for this is that there is a different price for each. If you paid 20 c/kWh for imported energy you might be lucky to get 10 c/kWh for exported energy. The reason for this is the cost of operating the grid.

Note that for billing purposes electrical energy is measured in **kWh**, not kW (which is a measure of power).